# HTML input tag passing placeholder as value to PHP

Tags: php, html, forms

I'm trying to implement the 'placeholder' attribute on a new mobile web site. Running into an issue where if a user leaves the field blank (showing the placeholder) then that placeholder is submitted as the field value for PHP to receive and place in the database. Instead it should (I assume) be sending an empty value. This causes problems with server side validation - the receiving PHP script thinks a legitimate value has been submitted instead of an empty value which would throw an error back to the user.

I am hoping there is a quick fix to this issue.

Sample code below:

```
<form action="somepage.php" method="post">

<input type="text" name="yourName" placeholder="Enter your name here">

<input type="submit">

</form>
```

PHP sees:

```
$_POST['yourName'] = 'Enter your name here';
```

instead of:

```
$_POST['yourName'] = '';
```

The latter is what I want it to see.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!!!

* EDIT ****

Here is an example form with the problem:

https://www.badgleymischka.com/mobileTest.php

Leave all fields as is (note in the source these are filled in by the placeholders, not the values). Click the "CONTINUE" button and you will see the _POST variables with the placeholder values.

Comment: `placeholder` is a HTML5 property. Do you have the right doctype set (i.e. `<!DOCTYPE html>`)?

Comment: Not a solution so far, but might help in the future and surely will help now: put `required` inside your `<input>` at some point eg `<input type="text" name="yourName" placeholder="Enter your name here" required>`

Comment: Could you provide code to reproduce it? Posted HTML form works fine (even though I just used `<html><head></head><body>YOURFORM</body></html>`)

Comment: In [this(awful) W3Schools page test](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_input_placeholder), it works as you expected, but it seems to be in Classic ASP(Aarghh!)...

Comment: Are you including any javascripts for placeholder browser support?

Comment: Added example form: https://www.badgleymischka.com/mobileTest.php

Comment: Something is removing the `placeholder` attr text on page load on several inputs...hmm

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Something is removing the `placeholder` attr text on page load on several inputs...

Based on your source, you're calling two different jQuery scripts. Delete this found near your closing `<body />` tag. This ***may*** be conflicting with Foundation's included Placeholder plugin.

```
<script src="js/vendor/jquery.js"></script>
```

***But this is probably the culprit:*** Not sure what you're trying to write here. But this looks to be the issue. See `line 17` in `jquery.main.js`. Remove this **all**. I don't think it's needed and is conflicting.

```
// clear inputs on focus
function initInputs() {
    PlaceholderInput.replaceByOptions({
        // filter options
        clearInputs: true,
        clearTextareas: true,
        clearPasswords: true,
        skipClass: 'default',

        // input options
        wrapWithElement: false,
        showUntilTyping: false,
        getParentByClass: false,
        placeholderAttr: 'value' // <-- ding, ding! Prob the conflictor, if not this entire function
    });
}
```

Comment: Odd, here is an example form I posted demonstrating the issue. Looking forward to your feedback:
https://www.badgleymischka.com/mobileTest.php

Comment: So how about that mystery script? ;) +1 though for the answer.

Comment: Hey - I never ruled it out lol. Was just basing my answer off what I was given (re: $_POST data), which had nothing at all to do with the issue - clearly! You pegged it though. :D

Comment: Turns out this was the problem all along. Removing the script solves the problem. Thanks!!!!!

Answer (score 1):

I cannot reproduce your error. I tested it using Firefox 25 and 26, Chrome 31, IE 11, Opera 12.16 and Safari 5.1.7. And looking at the specification I don't believe that the placeholder is intended to be submitted - so you are indeed experiencing some kind of bug.

The only reason for this behavior I can think of is that you are including a (java)script in your HTML, aimed at browsers that don't support HTML5 (and the `placeholder` attribute). Such a script could be filling empty inputs with their placeholders, but failing to remove them before the form is submitted.

If this is indeed the case, and your problems are caused by such a script, you can solve them by either fixing the script or removing it completely. If you choose to fix the script, you'll need to make sure that inputs whose value equals their placeholder are reset to their default value.

Comment: This is not an answer

Comment: @kingkero I expended my answer, I think it should be a valid answer now.

Comment: Well that could possibly be a matter of debate. But since you are assuming and/or questioning, I personally would have posted it as a comment. Answers should be just such - answers. Even if you are right, how would one solve this? The solution to this now would be an answer ;)

Comment: You playing "what ifs" man? lol Base your answer on the code given. Not by some mystery script you think exists. Nor is this really an answer - more of a comment. Instead you should ask the OP if they're using a third-party script, troubleshoot, and submit an answer based off that.

Comment: @MikeBarwick OP doesn't give the complete HTML file, so how can I be sure that he isn't including some javascript in order to support older browsers? It's the most obvious reason for this behavior.

Comment: The most obvious?? I disagree. Solution looks to be rather simple, but we shall see. And if you're not sure, that's what the comments section is for ;)

Comment: @MikeBarwick solution? So you were able to reproduce the problem? Enlighten me.

Comment: Not saying it couldn't be a plug-in issue. But looks like a `doctype` issue. Could also be something on the server-side of things. The OP is not giving us much to work with and leaving us to believe he has all other potential areas covered...

Comment: Have you tested your doctype assumption? I have, using different doctypes and different browsers, but I can't reproduce the problem. But I agree, it would be helpful if OP could give us some more info.

Comment: Here is a sample file so you can see the issue in action:

https://www.badgleymischka.com/mobileTest.php

Click the "CONTINUE" button at the bottom WITHOUT changing / adding contents to any of the fields

Answer (score 0):

Just stumbled across this in my own search, so if anyone else is looking for an answer to this try this:

```
<input type="text" name="yourName" placeholder="Enter your name here" required>
```

By adding "required" to the input tag the user must fill out this field before submitting.

Comment: The OP's problem is about `placeholder` which has been passed to server side language.

Answer (score -1):

This should work like charm but i assume since its on mobile something is different.

One solution(i am sure there is a better one) is to check it with an if.
So if the value is the same as the place holder then make it blank and then continue your validations.

Also try to put val="".

Comment: How does PHP know which value is the placeholder?

Comment: well as i said i dont know whats wrong since its a mobile(and we dont know the browser), we dont have the rest of the code to check if he uses HTML 5 and i said its not the best solution, its just a solution.The PHP does not supposed to know what is in the placeholder but look at this "PHP sees:

$_POST['yourName'] = 'Enter your name here';" He said it. So i proposed to check it as a solution. Read the question first please.

Comment: It is not. Imagine different files, one form and one PHP interpreting it. How can the PHP know which value was the placeholder (unless you set it by default in both sides which isn't much of a solution but a ugly workaround that isn't even needed here because of the possibility of a "cleaning" JS function)?

Comment: I got what you are trying to say, sorry for that, yea its an ugly workarround, i will try to provide him a nice js function. I thought you said about the first value of the placeholder and i was like waa? :P

Comment: js function is not needed for this...!?

Comment: Mike Barwick is right, sorry if I expressed myself wrong. I meant if you needed a workaround, a JS version would probably be preferred. But here it is not needed

Comment: That's true, i agree with you.